# ios versions compatibility

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, compatibility, ipad-2

Just saw wiki article "[ios version history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_version_history)", which says that ios 5 is compatible with iPhone 3GS and greater devices. Does iPhone 3GS, iPad 1 and 2 really support storyboards and new components of iOS 5? or do they require a software update for being compatible with iOS 5?

Comment: iOS 5 *is* the software update.

Comment: right :) but with iOS 5 i meant the development framework, does iPhone 3GS and iPhone 4 by hardware does implement all the features of iOS 5 framework?

Comment: Storyboards and new frameworks have nothing to do with hardware. It's in the firmware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mix operating system with hardware. iPhone 3GS supports storyboard ONLY if it's running iOS5, otherwise not.

There can be some hardware related differences even if all devices use same iOS version, for example iPad without SIM card cannot make phone calls. Storyboard is not such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

> ios 5 is compatible with iPhone 3GS and greater devices

Means that users can update these devices to run iOS 5. They have to do the update for you to be able to use story board and other new features. But if they are still running iOS 4 or older versions, you can't.